# TFS 2015 Update 1 – TF255430: the database was partially upgraded during a failed upgrade

Tags: tfs-2015, tfs-migration

> TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team
>   Foundation databases:

---

TF400711: Error occurred while executing

> servicing step 'Upgrade Process Template Description column' for
>   component FrameworkToDev14M85 during ToDev14M85: 2 error(s) occurred
>   while executing upd_ProcessTemplateToDev14M85.sql script.Failed batch
>   starts on line: 6.Error: 5074, Level: 16, State: 1, Batch Line: 6,
>   Script Line: 11Message: The statistics 'Description' is dependent on
>   column 'Description'.Error: 4922, Level: 16, State: 9, Batch Line: 6,
>   Script Line: 11Message: 
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Description failed
>   because one or more objects access this column.================ Failed
>   batch begin ==========================--small table, so no need to
>   batchUPDATE tbl_ProcessTemplateDescriptorSET Description =
>   LEFT(Description, 1024)--no race condition as binaries aren't allowing
>   people to save > 1024 length templates
>   ALTER TABLE
>   tbl_ProcessTemplateDescriptor
>   ALTER COLUMN Description
>   NVARCHAR(1024)================ Failed batch end**

You get an error while upgrading Team Foundation Server 2012 to Update 1 with a “TF254027: You must correct all errors before you continue”, “TF255375: the configuration database that you specified cannot be used” and a “TF255430: the database was partially upgraded during a failed upgrade”.

Answer (score 1):

the error looks confusing and simple enough trying to alter the table
**Alter fails because statistics were auto generated in the table**

> tbl_ProcessTemplateDescriptor

run the following query in the tfs_configuration database

```
 SELECT 'DROP STATISTICS ' + Schema_NAME(d.Schema_id) + '.' + '['+ OBJECT_NAME(a.object_id) + '].[' + a.name  +']' FROM sys.stats a INNER JOIN sys.Objects d ON d.Object_id = a.object_id WHERE auto_created = 0 AND User_Created = 1
```

***Steps to fix it***
 1. Restore the tfs_configuration database from the backup you had before the update 1 was installed
 2. execute the results in above query in that restored database
 3. Rerun the Upgrade wizard for update 1
 4. All should be well and it succeeds

another query window which drops all statistics